# Java jUnit Birt ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.osgi.util.NLS

Tags: java, junit, birt

I got the following ClassNotFoundException-Exception, when I tried to create a .pdf-file with Birt:

I used jUnit to test my code. In Virgo everything works, but not with jUnit.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/osgi/util/NLS
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.jar.ServicePlatform.getExtensionRegistry(ServicePlatform.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.jar.ServicePlatform.createFactoryObject(ServicePlatform.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.Platform$1.run(Platform.java:297)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.Platform.createFactoryObject(Platform.java:293)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.osgi.util.NLS
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 44 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I added this to my pom.xml (in the project with the jUnit-test) everything works fine:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.apache.poi</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```